# jQuery change a textbox with a <select> option

Tags: jquery

I hope that you can help me :)... here I go.

I have the next problem, I need to change some textbox in a table but that values depends of a option in a  its something like this :

```
<select id="msgOptions">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
</select>
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="message" name="message"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So my idea it is if the option1 is selected message = "message1" or if the option2 is selected "message2". BUT a important thing ... im getting that  and  from a servlet and im putting it in a div.

So is that possible ? I tried with change jQuery method but it doesnt work ... maybe i did it bad..

Thanks for advance and sorry for my bad English..

I tried:

```
$("#opcionServicio").change(function(){ $("esEjecucionCuentaEjecucion").val('hola'); })
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: You forgot the js code you tried

Comment: "maybe i did it bad." For sure you did something bad, but what???

Comment: yes, like i said i tried different methods between change function (jquery), <select onchange="something"> but no goods results for me thats why im asking for help

Comment: $("#opcionServicio").change(function(){
 
  $("esEjecucionCuentaEjecucion").val('hola');
 }) this is the code that i tried... but maybe because im getting "opcionServicio" from servlet its something wrong..

Comment: @infeex Ask instead for fixing not working code by posting it in question, you should have accurate answers in few minutes

Comment: What is `#opcionServicio` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be as simple as:

```
$("#msgOptions").change(function(){
   $("#message").val(this.value) //In this case this is the selected option
   //$("#message").val("Other value")
});
```

Also if you're using

```
 $("esEjecucionCuentaEjecucion")
```

You need to specify what it is a class? an ID? Otherwise your selector won't find anything to apply it the value you're setting.

Class:

```
$(".esEjecucionCuentaEjecucion")
```

ID:

```
$("#esEjecucionCuentaEjecucion")
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gntb/1/)

Comment: nope :/ I tried something like that before and doesnt work... thats why im asking maybe its because im getting info from servlet and putting it in a div?...

Comment: Hm are you putting all the code wrapped inside the $(function(){}) ? I  Mean this will work and also it will work in your example. You need to use the $(function(){}) to run all your code when the DOM is ready. Or it will not find any element on your selectors.

Comment: Before the servlet request the select exists? or it's added after getting the info from the servlet?

Comment: im trying to edit my post but i cant... and nope it doesnt exist im getting all select code from servlet.

Comment: Ok then use event delegation this will add a handler wheter the element exists or it's added in the future. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8gntb/3/